# Nuxt redirect with props from middleware

Tags: nuxt.js

I have the following:

```
async middleware({ $axios, redirect }) {
    let res = await EventService.index($axios, '?liveevent=true')
    if (res.data.length > 0) {
        return redirect('/matchday')
    }
}
```

Is it possible to pass props to the `redirect()` function made available on the resulting page?

Something like so:

```
return redirect('/matchday', {
    props: {
        event: res.data[0]
    }
})
```